# How do I get the timezone of the message author in my discord server? (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

How would I add a footer that displays when the message was sent according to the persons time zone?

[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5gw6.jpg)

For example

```py
import discord
import datetime

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('Exodus Hub | !cmds'))
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    print(msg.created_at)
    print(msg.author)
    if msg.author == client.user:
        return
    if msg.content.lower() == '!getscript':
        if str(msg.channel) == 'bot-cmds':
            if 'Developers' in str(msg.author.roles):
                richembed = discord.Embed(title='Exodus Server Bot',colour=0xff0000, description='Sending....')
                date = datetime.datetime.now()
                richembed.set_footer(text=f'{date:%b} at {date:%H:%M}') #<--- Footer
                await msg.channel.send(content=None,embed=richembed)

client.run('redacted')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discord embeds have a `timestamp` field which can be set to a `datetime` object. Unfortunately, there is no way to determine a user's timezone through the API that Discord provides.

You can view the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.timestamp) for discord.py's embed data class.

Answer (score 0):

The `timestamp` field in the embed will actually show in the user's local time. However, you can also use [Timestamp Styles](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#message-formatting-timestamp-styles) to put local time elsewhere in the embed and/messsage. It needs to be in EPOCH *seconds*, not milliseconds:

```
// one hour from now
<t:${Math.floor(new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60 * 60000).getTime() / 1000)}:t>
```